# Separation character in array Bash/Shell

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

How can I control how an array separates its elements? If you do:

```
echo ${array[*]}
```

it displays:

```
element1 element2 element3
```

and I would like it to be:

```
element1:element2:element3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements are joined by the first character of `$IFS` (internal field separator).

```
(IFS=':'; echo "${array[*]}")
```

Modifying `$IFS` has a lot of side effects. I recommend only changing it for a short duration inside a subshell so the rest of your script isn't affected.

Comment: Note that the double-quotes around `${array[*]}` are required for this to work right. Without them, it would join the elements with colons, then immediately re-split them (based on colons, 'cause that's in `$IFS` and word-splitting is what happens to unquoted variable references). The re-splitting completely reverses the joining operation (and might also split any elements that contain colon). It then passes the re-split elements to `echo`, which re-joins them, but with spaces this time (because `echo` doesn't pay attention to `$IFS`). Always double-quote your variable references.